# Baum-welch algorithm: probabilities after each step

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

In an effort to understand machine learning, at least to some degree, I've been implementing the various algorithms to solve the three problems in a Hidden Markov Model. I've been using [Rabiner's tutorial paper](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4758/2012sp/materials/hmm_paper_rabiner.pdf) as a guide.

I have had some trouble making the Baum-Welch algorithm work - namely, the probability after re-estimation is occasionally lower than before. The paper states that the result of a Baum-Welch step is either a critical point, or more likely than the previous step. This means my implementation is incorrect.

For the purposes of debugging, I would like to know if this property is true for each variable (e.g. the initial distribution, transition matrix and emission matrix) in isolation, or only when they all are applied. I tried to follow the proof from the [original Baum paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-27/issue-2/Growth-transformations-for-functions-on-manifolds/pjm/1102983899.full), but it was beyond my mathematical ability!

Comment: I think you might need to provide more details about how you’re updating parameters for this question to be answerable.